# Is it possible to adjust an indivdual's score based on their calculated bias?

Tags: survey, ordinal-data, bias

This question might not be right for this site, if so I apologize.

Today I was going over some basic survey results. There are 15 questions on this survey, about as many participants. Each questions is structured like so:

> On a scale of 1-10... rate the usefulness of...

If I had a large enough sample, I would feel comfortable just averaging the rating for each question and calling it good (I am not a statistician by any means). But I noticed as I was looking over each survey that the term "useful" varies a lot from person to person. One participant gave each question an 10 unless it specifically did not work. Another participant gave each question a 5 unless they had a specific comment about it.

In retrospect, I should have made the questions short response since there were so few participants, but I don't have the ability to resurvey.

Is there a way to adjust the data I have to minimize the effects of individual bias? Perhaps a different way to represent that data?

I was thinking about finding the average rating and std dev for each user, and adjusting a user's rating based on how "extreme" that rating is for them. For example, if someone's baseline rating is 9 or 10, then a 6 or 7 probably means a lot to them. Someone who puts mostly 5's or 6's means a lot by putting a 10, etc.

I'm just figuring since there is so much bias in the original data that I have nothing to lose by adjusting it and getting slightly more accurate data.